# Display items in ComboBox where item's bool property equals other bool property

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a List< SerialPort> where items have IsOpen property equals true or false. I want to display only items where IsOpen equals CheckBox.IsChecked property.

ViewModel code:

```
    private ObservableCollection<SerialPort> _PortsCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<SerialPort> PortsCollection
    {
        get { return _PortsCollection; }
        set { _PortsCollection = value; OnPropertyChanged("PortsCollection"); }
    }
    private SerialPort _SelectedPort;
    public SerialPort SelectedPort
    {
        get { return _SelectedPort; }
        set { _SelectedPort = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPort"); }
    }
    private bool _CheckBoxChecked;
    public bool CheckBoxChecked
    {
        get { return _CheckBoxChecked; }
        set { _CheckBoxChecked = value; OnPropertyChanged("CheckBoxChecked"); }
    }
```

XAML:

```
        <ComboBox
            Width="100"
            Height="23"
            DisplayMemberPath="PortName"
            ItemsSource="{Binding PortsCollection}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPort}"/>
        <CheckBox
            Content="Show ports where IsOpen == CheckBoxChecked"
            IsChecked="{Binding CheckBoxChecked}"/>
```

I've tried to do that with converter but converter allows only one parameter. I don't want to separate parameters in the converter because it's ugly. Any idea how to do this without separation parameters in converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it. I'd change what the PortsCollection returns depending on the value of CheckBoxChecked,

```
private List<SerialPort> _AllPorts;

public ObservableCollection<SerialPort> PortsCollection
{
    get 
    { 
        return new ObservableCollection<SerialPort>(_AllPorts.Where(x => x.IsOpen == CheckBoxChecked));
    }
    set { _PortsCollection = value; OnPropertyChanged("PortsCollection"); }
}
```

and tell the GUI that the PortsCollection has changed when the checkbox changes.

```
private bool _CheckBoxChecked;
public bool CheckBoxChecked
{
    get { return _CheckBoxChecked; }
    set { _CheckBoxChecked = value; 
          OnPropertyChanged("CheckBoxChecked"); 
          OnPropertyChanged("PortsCollection"); 
         }
}
```

I don't think there's a way to apply a filter in XAML

Comment: Wow, the solution was so simple. Thanks!